# pandas Selecting columns on the basis of dtype

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df with many columns i only want to process the columns with object datatype for that i had tried

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
get_cat=FunctionTransformer(lambda x:x if x.dtype==np.dtype(object) else None,validate=False)
get_cat.fit_transform(df)
```

but i am getting error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

but if i do same operation with column names as

```
get_cat=FunctionTransformer(lambda x:x[[col_names]],validate=False)
```

its working fine.
i am using Function transformer to get the data in sklearn Pipline for machine learning.

Comment: So whats your question? Add more detail and if possible more code.

Comment: i had updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier/clearer to build a custom transformer. Additionally, it can be easily applied in a pipeline

It could look like this:

```
class SelectDtypeColumnsTransfomer(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, dtype=object):
        self.dtype = dtype

    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        """ X : pandas DataFrame """

        columns = X.columns[X.dtypes == self.dtype]
        trans = X[columns].copy()
        return trans

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
```

An example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2], 'B': ['s', 'd'], 'c':['test', 'r']})
print(SelectDtypeColumnsTransfomer(np.int64).transform(df))
   A
0  1
1  2
print(SelectDtypeColumnsTransfomer(object).transform(df))
   B     c
0  s  test
1  d     r
```

**Concerning the use in pipelines:**

You should ensure that the columns in training and test set have the same dtypes. Depending on how you preprocess the data it might be that e.g. in the training set a column is of type float (including a nan) and in the test set it's of type int (no nan), or vice versa. In that case you need to adapt the fit function which sholud fix the columns during fitting and make further considerations ensuring consistent dtypes in the following steps of the pipeline

Comment: Good Solution to the problem.I really appreciate this.thanks

Comment: I corrected the transform function. It  should only contain `X` not `df`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use some like this

```
df_dtypes = df.dtypes.values.tolist()
select_dtype = np.dtype('int64')
select_cols = [True if x ==  select_dtype else False for x in df_dtypes]
```